# How to use the same picture for all Mysql record

Tags: php, mysql

Good evening,
I have a little issue. I have the class and I had to create php store. So, I was able to create it inputting all the information into SQL code via insert.

```
CREATE TABLE Products (
id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
imageLocation VARCHAR(200),
productName VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
productDesc VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
price DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL,
```

This was my original input

```
INSERT INTO Products (imageLocation, productName, productDesc, price)
VALUES ("images/item1.jpg","Item1","Item1 is here",9.99);
```

But after that, I realized that my requirements states that I have to build backend with adding, deleting and updating records. I was able to do that except pictures. I would like to know if there is a way to hardcode default picture for all the records. Since I realized that building separate thing for uploding images would be to much for the noob like me.
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

Comment: Of course you can hardcode if you know the image path (or name) .Why don't you can?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE `Products` MODIFY `imageLocation` VarChar( 200 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'images/item1.jpg';
```

should do the trick.

But OFC is not good idea to do management panel with only partial support.
If you dont know how to do this youo can try to convince your "client" to put files in specified format on FTP server or sth like this and generate correct names in DB or on the fly.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that default constraint will do wonders :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the default image location using the [IFNULL](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-ifnull/) function as illustrated below:

```
SELECT id, IFNULL(imageLocation,'images/item1.jpg') imageLocation, productName, productDesc, price 
FROM Products;
```

Comment: Thnak you for your time. Learn something new everyday :)